# Google Compute Engine IO monitoring

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a ubuntu 14.04 running on compute engine f1-micro instance. Once in a few weeks the server is hung because of a burst of IO reads.

[GCE monitor screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bluv.png)

I can't use SSH to connect when it happens.

This server used to hung at a specific time everyday, I found it was the auto update of apt.

Now the auto-update configuration is:

```
$/etc/apt/apt.conf.d# cat 10periodic
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "1";
$/etc/apt/apt.conf.d# cat 20auto-upgrades
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Is there any way to monitor and detect what caused the IO burst, even when SSH can't be connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Console offers basic IO monitoring for GCE instances (you've already seen it in your screenshot). However, is also possible to provide more advanced monitoring by using the [Stackdriver Monitoring Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#joint-install), which is a process in your machine that gathers different metrics and sends them to [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/).

One additional advantage of this approach, is that it can be used alongside [Stackdriver Alerts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) to let you know when things are going south with a certain metric. However, one drawback might be the resource overhead of the agent collecting metrics in your system, particularly considering the machine size.

Alternatively, you can use the [Sysstats suite](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/) to collect metrics within the machine via `sar` (and relatives) using a simple CronJob.

The only downside is that, metric information is, by default, preserved in the same machine, so it might be more like *post-mortem* data than *preventive* data.

Finally, is not stated what is being run in your machine, but if possible, you might as well consider another machine size for your workloads not being so resource-contrained.

Comment: I checked that f1-micro gives me 0.2 vCPU, so I suppose it is already fully loaded when the monitor showing CPU usage of 0.2 CPU/utilization, and any usage higher than that is "bursting capability". So it is CPU overhead that hangs the server.

Comment: I mainly use it as a server for learning and experimenting, so just upgraded to g1-small and installed Stackdriver to see what the weekly spike of IO is.